# What is the difference between a taught M.Phil and a taught M.Sc?

Tags: masters, titles

I have a specific taught M.Phil in mind, which is definitely not a precursor to a PhD.  In fact, strangely, doing a PhD after the course is discouraged since the M.Phil in question is more of a vocational course.

Given that the subject matter of a taught M.Phil could be considered to be 'science' what are the criteria for deciding whether a Masters course should be either an M.Phil or an M.Sc?

Comment: Country, university, and accreditation rules all differ across the world. At some institutions one can get either a BA or a BS in the same major, with the differences not always that clear. But, the fact that the M.Phil is aimed more as a vocational course would indicate that there is not much emphasis on theory and research.

Comment: In what country? In the USA, the M. Phil is generally given to PhD students who pass all their courses, exams, and proposals, but leave before finishing a dissertation. It may be something entirely different in other countries.

Comment: I was referring to UK.  It is an M.Phil at the University of Cambridge.

Answer (score 2):

M. Phil at the University of Cambridge is just what they call all of their post-graduate masters courses. There are no MSc's at Cambridge. Similarly, there are no BSc's at Cambridge. Science students get a BA like everyone else.

In general a university can use whatever title they want for their masters degrees, there are no criteria.